# Data grapsh for local IP addresses in pfSense

Tags: proxy, freebsd, network-monitoring, pfsense

I am using pfSense as router with LightSquid transparent proxy.
Reports that LightSquid offers me are great, I can see amount of data transfered trought router, grouped by hours,months,weeks, Also I can compare local addresses one with others in tabular report,
So I can see which user is taking most of bandwidth.
Thats all works great but unfortunately only for traffic trough port 80. 
My question is there other way to collect and display data in nice way as it does LightSquid of traffic for all ports. I know that transparent proxy only catch WEB (80) , but I do not want to know structure of traffic, all I want to display traffic at all, If it can be spared by ports it will be great, if not does never-mind.

Answer (score 1):

There are many options. See this page: 
http://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/How_can_I_monitor_bandwidth_usage%3F